# BSL Copyright Notice

Tags: copyright, bsl

According to the BSL using Boost requires

> The copyright notices in the Software [...] must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole or in part, and all derivative works of the Software, unless such copies or derivative works are solely in the form of machine-executable object code generated by a source language processor

I'm not quite sure about this sentence. Do I have to grep all copyright notices from the source files/headers for the version I use, like somebody already did (https://github.com/Tencent/mars/blob/master/Copyright%20Notice%20of%20Boost)? That would be as far as I currently see over 2000 different statements.

Comment: *Using* it doesn't require that.  *Redistributing* it does.  Are you redistributing binaries-only, or are you redistributing source as well?

Comment: I'm linking boost static and using some headers. (e.g. from thread and chrono)
I plan to sell the product as a binary without any sources.

Answer (score 1):

The [Boost Software Licence](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSL-1.0) (BSL) requires that

> The copyright notices in the Software ... must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole or in part, and all derivative works of the Software

The copy you already have has all those entries in already.  Using it requires nothing further from you.  Should you wish to distribute copies, they, too, will already have those entries in.

Should you wish to make significant changes to Boost or excerpt a significant portion of it, and redistribute it as part of your project *complete with source*, then the approach the github user you link to has taken strikes me as a fairly pragmatic one, and one which ensures that no copyright line will get left out merely because you haven't needed to use the particular source file in which it occurs.  2000 lines might seem like a lot, but the Boost libraries (v1.69.0) weigh in at some 4.3MLOC, so if the libraries are useful to you then the obligation seems fairly light, at least to me.

But if you're redistributing binary-only ("*solely in the form of machine-executable object code generated by a source language processor*") which you now say you are, then you have no obligation to redistribute *any* of those lines.

Comment: About the 2000 lines I'm not quite sure how to take them. Many authors are included multiple times (but only the year/range of years) is different. May I "shrink" them? (e.g. once 2007 once 2007-2009 and once 2011 ... may I combine them to one line?)

Comment: @Florian see my edit above.